# Резолв большего кол-ва доменов

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

Нужно около 500к доменов, сейчас постоянно уходит в

> cURL error 6: Couldn't resolve host name

В /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

В /etc/resolv.conf

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
nameserver x.x.x.x #host provider ns-server
nameserver x.x.x.x #host provider ns-server
```

Как можно протюнить? Добавить больше ns-серверов? php-curl каким образом чекает?

Comment: исходя из опыта, я бы скорее убрал провайдерские ns-ы. // а запрашиваемые имена точно зарегистрированы?

Comment: а ещё лучше — пользоваться локальным (рекурсивным кэширующим) ns-сервером.

Comment: @alexander-barakin, спасибо, убрал, посмотрим. Кеш смысла ставить наверно не имеет, там все домены разные идут.

Comment: Установил, спасибо. Разве резолвится вся зона?

Comment: да, пожалуй, я неправильно сформулировал мысль. она была относительно альтернативы: использовать кэширующий или не-кэширующий локальный ns.

Answer (score 2):

Решил установкой pdnsd

Часть конфига

```
server {
    label = "recurse";
    root_server = on;
    randomize_servers = on; // Берем случайный сервер
    ip = 8.8.8.8,
         8.8.4.4,
         77.88.8.8,
         77.88.8.1,
         209.244.0.3,
         84.200.69.80,
         8.26.56.26,
         208.67.222.222,
         156.154.70.1,
         199.85.126.10
    ;
    timeout = 5;
    uptest = query;
    interval = 30m;      // Test every half hour.
    ping_timeout = 300;  // 30 seconds.
    purge_cache = off;
    exclude = .localdomain;
    policy = included;
    preset = off;
}
```